# Using awk to format an output for nstats

Tags: awk

I would like to get a complete hostname with their server up-time using "nstats" command. The script appears to be working ok. I need help with the 1st column with a "complete" hostname and the 7th column (server up-time) printed.

**This following command only give me their partial hostnames:**

```
 for host in $(cat servers.txt); do nstats $host -H | awk 'BEGIN {IFS="\t"} {$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$9="" ; print}' ; done
```

**BAD Output**: (host-names got cut off after the 12th characters)

```
 linux_server  223 days
 linux_server  123 days
 windows_serv  23 days
 windows_serv  23 days
```

**EXPECTED Output**:

```
 linux_server1   223 days
 linux_server2   123 days
 windows_server1  23 days
 windows_server2  123 days
```

**The contents of servers.txt file are as follows:**

```
 linux_server1
 linux_server2
 windows_server1
 windows_server2
```

**Output without awk**

```
 LINXSERVE10% for host in $(cat servers.txt); do nstats $host -H ; done
 linux_server   0.01    47%    22%    56  05:08  20 days 17:21:00
 linux_server   0.00    23%     8%    45  05:08  24 days 04:16:46
 windows_serv   0.04    72%    30%    58  05:09 318 days 23:32:17
 windows_serv   0.00    20%     8%    40  05:09 864 days 12:23:10
 windows_serv   0.00    51%    17%    41  05:09 442 days 05:30:14
```

Note: `for host in $(cat servers.txt); do nstats $host -H | awk -v server=$host 'BEGIN {IFS="\t"} {$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$9="" ; print server }' ; done` *** this works ok but it will list only a complete hostname with no server uptime.

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you show what is the output of one `nstats $host -H`? Also, it would be best to do `while read host; do ... ; done < servers.txt`. No need to `for host in $(cat ...)`.

Comment: The awk command itself does not cut the output of fields.

Comment: Can still use "awk" to echo the server uptime with a variable $host? Something like {print $host,$7,$8}';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know you may choose the fields to print in awk?

```
for host in $(cat servers.txt); do
    nstats $host -H |
    awk 'BEGIN {IFS="\t"} {print $1,$7,$8}';
done
```

These will print only three fields you are interested.

The awk code labeled as a "note" is totally useless -- It is equivalent to

```
for host in $(cat servers.txt); do
    echo "$host"
done
```

UPDATE: after realizing the problem was the **nstats** command, the awk line command would be

```
    awk -v server="$host" 'BEGIN {IFS="\t"} {print server,$7,$8}';
```

then the output looked like this (server uptime overwrote the hostnames)

```
20 daysrver  
24 daysrver  
318 daysver 
864 dayserv  
442 dayserv
```

So I put that server variable at the end, it looked much better and i can extract that and play with it in excel. THANKS SO Much Jdamian!

```
 for host in $(cat servers.txt); do nstats $host -H | awk -v server="$host" 'BEGIN {IFS="\t"} {print $7,$8,server}'; done

 20 days linux_server1
 24 days linux_server2
 318 days windows_server1
 864 days windows_server2
 442 days windows_server3
```

Comment: I tried that script and it still gave me the same result with partial hostnames and the server uptime.

for host in $(cat servers.txt); do
    nstats $host -H |
    awk 'BEGIN {IFS="\t"} {print $1,$7,$8}';
done

Comment: Please, add the output of the **nstats $host -H**, i.e., remove the awk command and run the loop.

Comment: LINXSERVE10% for host in $(cat servers.txt); do nstats $host -H ; done
linux_server   0.01    47%    22%    56  05:08  20 days 17:21:00
linux_server   0.00    23%     8%    45  05:08  24 days 04:16:46
windows_serv   0.04    72%    30%    58  05:09 318 days 23:32:17
windows_serv   0.00    20%     8%    40  05:09 864 days 12:23:10
windows_serv   0.00    51%    17%    41  05:09 442 days 05:30:14
LINXSERVE10%

Comment: Do you realize that the nstats command is cutting off the server names and not the awk command?

Comment: Oh Ok. Thanks for that great answer. Is there anyway I can still use :awk" for the server uptime and the variable $host? Something like  {print $host,$7,$8}';

Comment: Substitute your awk line for the awk line I posted at the end of my answer.

Comment: YOU GOT WHAT I NEEDED Jdamian !!!! 
THANKS SO MUCH!!!
TRULY APPRECIATE YOUR HELP.